# Extract string between two string with regex in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I need to extract, from a text, only the strings like "THIS STRING":

text = **771458**">THISSTRING<span data-academy-id="co-favorit

The bold part is random... so I need to identify the string between **6 digits + ">** and the string **<span data-academy-id="co-favorit**.

I have, in the same text, many time this case. So I need to keep all string like this.

Thank u!

Comment: it can be done using `\d{6}">(.*?)\<span data-academy-id=\"co-favorit` just need to use the `{}` to make sure your matching a fixed number of digits with a non greedy match all in between

Comment: Why not simply extract between > and < using for example `re.findall(f">(.+)<", text)[0]`

Comment: @KaranShishoo can u help me with exact code? thank u

Comment: You can do this:
`pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\d{6}">).*(?=<span data-academy-id="co-favorit)')`
`result = pattern.search(text)`